# html div pixel offset other than float

Tags: html, offset

I'm tiring to learn html. I want to set up a  block inside another. I want this block to be 20 pixels away from the existing block on each side accept the top where I want it 100 pixels away from the top of existing block.

I know the size of the div block that conforms to this specification to be a 1160 by 480 pixel block. What I'm looking for and what I assumed existed before designing my layout is some sort of "center" attribute I could use on the  so that magically place it at the center of the existing structure. Sadly I can not find such an attribute.

I was wondering if you guys could help me out. Is there some way of aligning or offsetting the pixel placement of a  block besides the float attribute?

On a side note, is there some site that list's all attributes associated with all html elements?

Here's my code:

```
<div id="container" style="width:1600px">
        <div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;width:1600px;height:50px;">
            Navigation bar
        </div>

        <div id="links" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:750px;width:400px;float:left;">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Resume</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="">facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Linkedin</a></li>
                <li><a href="">youtube</a></li>
                <li><a href="">twitch</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="Ticker Title" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:150px;width:1200px;float:left;">
            Title of the Ticker goes here
        </div>

        <div id="Ticker block main" style="background-color:#CCCCCC;height:600px;width:1200px;float:left;">
            Main ticker block with a cool background.
            <div id="Ticker block" style="background-color:#BBBBBB;height:480px;width:1160px;" align="center">
                Ticker that displays one of five recent event. Refreshing the cycle every 20 secs. Can't get to display correctly within ticker main
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please include the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear on your desired functionality.
However, here are two methods of centering your inner box.

---

**METHOD 1**

If you want the inner box to be 100px from the top of its container and 20px from each side, you can simply remove width (and height, if you like) settings from the inner box and configure its margins:

```
div#ticker_block {
    background-color:#BBBBBB;
    height:480px;
    margin:100px 20px 0px 20px;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xHW72/)

---

**METHOD 2**

Since you know the dimensions of both the inner and outer box, you can set the inner box's `top` to "50%" and set a negative `margin-top` to half of the box's height. This centers the inner box vertically. Then set `margin-left` and `margin-right` to "auto" to center it horizontally:

```
div#ticker_block {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#BBBBBB;
    height:480px;
    width:1160px;
    margin:-240px auto 0px auto;
    top:50%;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FA6Xf/1/)

---

In reference to your last question, you can find HTML 4 specs here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/

P.S. I renamed the ID of `Ticker block` to `ticker_block`, as IDs with spaces are not valid:

From the [HTML 4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: Sweet! It worked. So you can use the margin attribute with div blocks ehh? Cool. Method one worked but I had to decrease the first number to 80. Method 2 worked perfectly. I wasn't comfortable with the syntax you used so I changed mine to look like this: <div id="Ticker_block" style="background-color:#BBBBBB;height:480px;width:1160px;position:relative;margin:-240px auto 0px auto;top:50%;"> for method 2 and <div id="Ticker_block" style="background-color:#BBBBBB;height:480px;width:1160px; margin:100px 20px 0px 20px;"> for method 1. Thanks for the specs btw!

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use CSS to center it horizontally like so:

text-align: center;

But, that won't get you the vertical centering you'r looking for.